# If css("top") is or greater then -70 (negative value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, negative-number

This is my piece of code which does **not** work.

```
if ( $("div#verticalScrollbar").css("top") >= -70+"px" ) {
        alert("does work!");
    }
```

I literally WANT to say: If the top position is -70 or greater (like -71, -100, -444, etc.) then do the alert.

Comment: `-100` is smaller than `-70`.... but your actual problem is that you are comparing strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-100` is *lower* than `-70`, not greater - thats one problem here. another one is you're comparing string where you should compare numbers - just use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
if ( parseInt($("div#verticalScrollbar").css("top"), 10) <= -70 ) {
    alert("does work!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to compare numerically. jQuery’s `css` method returns a string, so you need to convert it to a number, using JavaScript’s built-in [`parseInt`](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Parsing_Numbers) function:

```
if(parseInt($("div#verticalScrollbar").css("top"), 10) <= -70) {
    alert("does work!");
}
```

(Also, as pointed out by oezi, -100 is less than -70.)